# Reading a data file and storing into array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, file, data-structures

I'm attempting to read a data file and to store the information into an array of course structures (or an array of pointers to course structures). This assignment requires maintaining a database using an array of pointers to the student structures.

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I attempt to scan the data file into the array. How can I properly store the information from the file into the array?

```
#define SIZE        30
#define fieldLength 300
#define diskFile    "diskFile.dat"
#define courseFile  "course.dat"

struct student
{
    char name[fieldLength];
    int age[fieldLength]; 
    char course1[fieldLength];
    char course2[fieldLength];
    char remarks[fieldLength];      
}*sp[SIZE];

struct course 
{ 
    char name[fieldLength];
    char number[fieldLength];
    char instructor[fieldLength];
    char date[fieldLength];
    char starting[fieldLength];
    char ending[fieldLength];
    char location[fieldLength]; 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, count;

    struct course course_arr[SIZE]; // an array of ten structs

    FILE * in; /*FILE pointer to do the stream IO*/
    in = fopen(courseFile, "r+");

    count = 0;
    while ((fscanf(in, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", 
                       &course_arr[count].name, 
                       &course_arr[count].number,
                       &course_arr[count].instructor, 
                       &course_arr[count].date, 
                       &course_arr[count].starting, 
                       &course_arr[count].ending, 
                       &course_arr[count].location)) != EOF)
    {       
        count++;        
    }

    /* print the menu */
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|\t%-20s","(N)ew record");
    printf("%-20s","(U)pdate record");
    printf("Swa(p) records\t|\n");
    printf("|\t%-20s","(S)ort database");
    printf("%-20s","(C)lear database");
    printf("(D)isplay db\t|\n");

    printf("|\t%-20s","(L)oad disk");
    printf("%-20s","(W)rite disk");
    printf("(E)mpty disk\t|\n");

    printf("|\t%-20s", "(V)iew courses"); 
    printf("%-20s","(R)emove record");
    printf("(Q)uit   \t|\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("choose one: ");
```

Comment: Buffer overflow is a real thing. Read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Routine `fscanf` never returns `EOF`.
Test `fscanf` to be less than the number of expected fields:

```
count = 0;
while((fscanf(in, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", &course_arr[count].name, &course_arr[count].number, &course_arr[count].instructor, &course_arr[count].date, &course_arr[count].starting, &course_arr[count].ending, &course_arr[count].location)) < 7){
     count++;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` does return `EOF`, see 7.21.6.2 ad 16 of the C11 standard.

Comment: oops yes, Actually EOF is returned after the file reading has been exhausted or a reading error. So I suggest to test the returned value different from 7, simply.

Answer (score 0):

i think that it is better to work with 
while(getline(string_variable,,)!=EOF).(look on the net on which argumentsto put in the getline)
Then work with the string_variable. Look at the format that the data is stored into the txt file. eg: name(blank)number(blank)instructor(blank)date(blank)starting(blank)endinglocation
Start looking for blanks in the string_variable. when you see the first blank copy the substring from position 1 to position blank-1 to  the course_arr[count].name variable.then delete the substring from position 1 to position blank. Look again for the first blank and store the substring to course_arr[count].number and so on.

Sorry for my English hope u got the meaning

Answer (score 0):

You should loose all the `&`s in the `fscanf` call. The `char` arrays are already passed as pointers. If you'd used the `-Wall` option on `gcc` (or a similar option for any other compiler) it will warn you for this as well.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the file what you are reading is present or not.

add bellow

```
 in = fopen(courseFile, "r+");

 if(in == NULL)
        {
        printf("exit");
        exit(0);
        }
```

I guess it might be the problem.